# ZSH binding 'Control-I' also binds 'Tab'

Tags: shell, zsh

I've got the following binding:

`bindkey '^I' openFzfDirectoryHistoryUnsorted`

However, with the above pressing 'Tab' also runs `openFzfDirectoryHistoryUnsorted` instead of the usual tab character.

I've also tried to reset the binding by adding:
`bindkey -r '^I'` before the above binding - with no change in behavior.

What is the cause for this? And how can I avoid it?

Comment: The tab key sends control/I.  That's standard behavior.

Comment: How do I disable that behavior?

Comment: You could change your keyboard configuration (details vary according to the terminal/platform) to make tab send something else.  But it would interfere with using the tab key in editing, etc.

Comment: Hmm seems to potentially be a complicated issue, I found a discussion of the aspects involved here: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5916